# How to render the same component on all screens?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-navigation

I have a `StackNavigator`, where I've specified the same headerRight `Icon` for every screen:

```
export default StackNavigator(
    {
        Authorization: {
            screen: AuthorizationScreen
        },
        SignIn: {
            screen: SignInScreen
        },
        SignUp: {
            screen: SignUpScreen
        },
        Main: {
            screen: MainScreen
        },
        Language: {
            screen: LanguageScreen
        },
        //...etc
    },
    {
        navigationOptions: {
            headerRight: (
                <Icon color={'#77767c'}
                      name='ios-contact-outline'
                      size={30}
                      style={{ paddingRight: 30}}
                      type='ionicon'
                />
            ),
        }
    }
)
```

All the screens are imported from separate files. When this `Icon` is pressed, I want the same component to render regardless of what screen I'm on. The problem is, I can't think of a way to do this outside of writing in some kind of state handling and `onPress` function for every single screen I have, which would be really tedious to write and maintain. Is there any way to get around this and only write the component rendering once?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create one component for **Header** and pass it into all the screen's **navigationOptions**. Then you just need to handle the method on each screen and you can do your stuff at here.

Custom Header Class:

```
class Header extends Component {
    render() {
        const props = this.props;
        return (<View>
            <View
                style={KEEP_YOUR_STYLE}
            />
            <View style={styles.containerStyle} >
                <Text
                    style={your_style}
                    numberOfLines={1}
                >TITLE</Text>

                <TouchableOpacity
                    style={styles.touchableOpacityStyle}
                    onPress={props.onPress}
                >
                    <Image
                        source={YOUR_ICON}
                        style={{
        position:'absolute',
        right: 10,
        width: 20,
        height: 20,
        resizeMode: 'cover',
    }
}            />}
                </TouchableOpacity>                
            </View>
        </View>
        );
    }
}
export { Header };
```

In your StackNavigator:

```
const defaultNavigation = ({ navigation }) => ({
    header: (<Header
        title='Hellow'
    />),
});

Language: {
    screen: LanguageScreen,
    navigationOptions: defaultNavigation,
},
```

In your particular Screen:

```
 static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => ({
        header: (
            <Header
                title='Your Title'
                onPress={() => { 
                    // DO YOUR STUFF
                }}
            />),
    });
```